# Finding Distance from ray to 3D bezier-curve

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, math

I'm wondering if anyone knows how to find the smallest distance from a 3D line segment or ray to a 3D cubic-bezier curve or if there is anything built into the Unity game engine.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on your question. Can you please add more information to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate affine transformation that transform ray base point into `(0,0,0)` and direction becomes `OX`

If ray is defined by base point `(rx0, ry0, rz0)` and direction vector  `(dx, dy, dz)` with length `len` (1 for normalized), then matrix of this transform is product of:

- shift by `(-rx0, -ry0, -rz0)` -
- then rotation around `OZ` axis by `atan2(ry, rx)`
- then rotation around `OY` axis by `acos(dz / len)`

Apply this transform to Bezier curve contol points

Calculate minimal distance from curve to `OX` axis using zer0derivative approach (derivative is zero for max and min of function):

Write expression for squared distance depending of `t`:

```
SquaredDist(t) = by'(t)^2  + bz'(t)^2
```

Calculate derivative of `SquaredDist` by `dt`, make equation

```
SquaredDist' = 0
```

and solve it against `t`.

Equation is 5-th order polynomial equation, so no analytical, only numerical solution (or subdivision approach).

Check roots in `0..1` interval, also check Bezier curve ends and ray start point distance separately.